# incorrect joins - 1 row per result set

Tags: sql, merge, windows-server-2003

I trying to determine which people in my databases have either unsubscribed from my news letters, which people have bad email addresses and which dont have either. I have activities activities for both iUnsub' and 'iBadEmail'.

the code i wrote was

```
select distinct 

n.id,
'Unsubscribe' =
            case
            when a.activity_type = 'iUnsub' then '1'
            end,
'Bad Email' = 
            case
            when a.activity_type = 'iBadEmail' then '1'
            end


from name n
left join activity a on n.id = a.id


where n.id in

(
'1002421',
'1005587',
'1009073',
'1001102'
)
```

the results i receive creates 2 results for each id

```
id  Unsubscribe Bad Email

1001102  NULL            NULL

1002421  NULL            NULL

1002421  1           NULL

1005587  NULL            NULL

1005587  1           NULL

1009073  NULL            1

1009073  NULL            NULL
```

i would like to the code to only give me one row for each id like below

```
id  Unsubscribe Bad Email

1001102 NULL    NULL

1002421 1   NULL

1005587 1   NULL

1009073 NULL    1
```

Comment: Please provide a complete small working example of input data that can be used to verify your code. At this point all we see is some code and some output, and there is nothing to tell us where the joins should be and what you're doing wrong.

Comment: try it with inner join or with some other logic, left join always  increases the number of null values in the result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple activity rows 3 or your names, and you are returning a row in the result for each activity.  Name 1001102 either has no or only one activity which is neither Unsub or BadEmail.

```
select n.Id, 
      sum(case when a.activity_id = 'iUnSub' then 1 else 0 end) UnSub,
      sum(case when a.activity_id = 'iBadEmail' then 1 else 0 end) BadEmail    
from name 
left outer join activity a on n.id = a.id
where a.activity 
and n.id in
(
'1002421',
'1005587',
'1009073',
'1001102'
)
group by n.Id
```

This will give you a non-zero figure if UnSubbed or BadEmail, and if both are 0, then it's presumably OK.

The `left outer join` is for cases whene a name has no activity rows. If you don't include that then they will not be included in the output. If that's fine, change it to an inner join.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. This code worked aprt from i had to take the a.activity out of the where clause.